# Nodes not visible for material created in properties panel

Tags: materials, interface, node-editor

Materials created in material properties are not showing up in the node editor in blender 2.70.  Is there something I need to turn on?  I've looked in user preferences and I don't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 16):

Here are some possible causes:

1. You're working in Blender Internal rather than cycles:
   [image]
2. You're working with the compositing nodes:
   [image]
   Make sure that the selected option is the little ball, *not* the one that's selected in the image.
3. Your view is not in the right place. Hit the <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> key on your number pad. If nothing happens, hit <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Numpad .</kbd>.
4. Make sure use nodes is checked

Comment: I checked that before I asked the question and it was in the right position.  I had to restart the program and made sure it was in cycles from the start and that fixed the problem.  Thanks very much.

Comment: @Rmathews951 If this helped you, please mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

Or make sure the "Use Nodes" Checkbox is checked in the Node Editor.

Comment: I'm baffled by the nasty UI in blender.
You answer was correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In `Compositing` tab, `Find Nodes` under `Select` in the menu. Reference from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/224261/125135).

Hope it helps.