# All options are greyed out and inaccessible in the node editor

Tags: materials, node-editor

[image]If I go to the Node editor and press Shift+A every action is grey and I can´t click anything. I started to model a waffle(I'm at the very beginning of modelling) and wanted to make a material for it in the node editor but every action in Shift+A is grey and unclickable. Even returning to factory settings doesn´t help. Here is the project:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdqqbnyq57cgwng/Waffel.blend?dl=0

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: did you enable "Use Nodes"?

Comment: Hi. Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for more permanent blend file hosting. Also, uploading a blend file should be secondary to a clear description of the problem (which you have done) and preferably some images to illustrate your point. Ideally, we want to try and answer the question without having to rely on a file to be downloaded.

Comment: I have solved the problem myself

Comment: @Abraskus Then please post an answer below in the answer box.

Comment: You found one more way to make node adding menu greyed out which wasn't outlined [in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14425/nodes-not-visible-for-material-created-in-properties-panel), which is trying to add nodes to object when it doesn't have any material. Object must have a material for nodes

Comment: The solution was just changing a few things and switching from Blender Render to Cycles Render.

Comment: When you say the solution was "changing a few things" what do you mean?  Others with a similar problem could use your experience.

Comment: I am having the same issue, only I cannot at all find where I can select new material in the bottom bar location, however, in the right side tool menu, I have already added a new material and messed around with that and nothing seems to be working. I cannot find a way to make this work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a new material.
Press "New" in the bar below the node-editor window.

[image]

make sure the "use nodes" is ticked.

[image]

Comment: Would be good if you showed the screenshot *before* you pressed 'New'. It might be hard for a user to understand where they would see the 'New' button going by your screenshot.

Comment: the new shows on the screenshot of Abraskus. At least that was my train of thought. i wanted to show the use node checkbox. - added it anyways.