# Rendered Image not showing up in compositing tab

Tags: render-layers, compositing-nodes

I am new to blender and I am following Blender Guru's donut (beginner) tutorial. I am having problem in compositing tab. When I do render and switch to compositing tab, the rendered image is not shown in **Render Layers** node. I tried searching online for solution but most of them were for blender 2.7.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
here is my `.blend` file. Hope this helps.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xVGiCHVZDOJdPxW_G_znPUeDL5GtpeI2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you pressed on the Backdrop button (Compositor header menu bar)?

Comment: The preview image in the Render Layers node might not always update after rendering. However, you should still get the correct final image. To view the output of any node, you can use the Viewer Node (Add > Output > Viewer). If you connect it to the Render Layers node, it should display your last rendered image in the background.

Comment: @moonboots, yes I have pressed the backdrop button. But still the rendered image is not shown.

Comment: The linked file seems to be private.

Comment: Try enabling "use nodes" from the top of your compositing window.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. None of these solutions listed here seemed to help. I fiddled around and found an answer for myself. Hope it works for you. Seems the render had not loaded on the time line so I had to nudge it.

Go to the time line at the bottom of the screen and move the pointer on 0 seconds up a bit and the preview showed up for me. I then put it back to 0 seconds and the preview persisted.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and i found out on my own how to get it to show next to the 'add' and 'node' menus there is a use node check box make sure that is checked. i checked mine and it popped up for me. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

easiest way to solve the issue is by clicking use nodes on[image] the toolbar when in composting mode

Answer (score 0):

Add a viewer node or if your Node Wranglar is enable controll + shift left click on the Render layes

Comment: Tried it but nothing changed. I have added link to .blend file if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem lies in that the targeted node was **not found (but it's there!)** in the scene.

I solved this problem as follow:

1. Render the image.
2. In `Compositing` tab, click `Select` in the menu.
3. Click `Find Nodes` and click/search your targeted "nodes" (e.g. `Render Layers`)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I started by deleting the Render Layers node: Right Click on node then press <kbd>Del</kbd>

Then I added the node again: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> *Input > Render Layers*

Once I added it again, the rendered image showed in the Render Layers node

I then added the Composite node as well: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> *Output > Composite*

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me but there is a tab on the right edge of the *Compositor* named *View*. In you'll find the *Reset Backdrop* button, which solved the problem for me.

[image: Reset Backdrop]

Answer (score 0):

'Scene' and 'View Layer' at the bottom of the 'Render Layers' block (vertically-oriented rectangle) is critical: They should both be present. There is a little film-roll icon to the right of "View layer". Use that to open your image and you are good. Of course, you should have already opened your image in 'Layout' at the very beginning. Absolutely NO ONE has mentioned this little film-roll icon anywhere.

And, Yes, make sure 'Use Nodes' is chosen, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be:

1. You may not have rendered the image completely before compositing ( Yes, you have to render the scene once before compositing)
2. enable nodes
3. Enable backdrop option
4. You may not have added the veiwer node option.

Answer (score 0):

A thing worth mentioning is that sometimes Blender tickboxes have a hiccups, and have opposite effect than they claim. I have the version 3.1.0 and I was having the same grievance as you - but it just turned out that the "auto Render" tickbox actually disabled the Auto-Rendering lol.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when I was too far zoomed out. You can adjust that under *Zoom* in *View* (right-hand tab in Compositing window), or hit *Reset Backdrop* (as another poster suggested).

Answer (score 0):

When you don`t see the render result after opening composing, go to the top bar click *Render* and the click *Render Image*.

This will do the trick. You should be able to see your render in the *Composing* tab.